# Custom filter at word level, not substring, in category autocomplete jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have thousands of data populated in autocomplete. If type a letter say,`a` all the labels with character `a` are shown but I need result that either contains `a` as a single word or starts with character `a`.

A little help here???

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it using json

```
$("#search")
                .catcomplete(
                        {
                            delay : 0,
                            source :function(request, response) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '<c:url value="/JSON/getDataAU.jspx"/>',
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data:request,
                                    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                        console.log( data);
                                        var items = data;
                                        response(items);
                                    },
                                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                         console.log(errorThrown);
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            select : function(event, ui) {
                                $('#form1')
                                        .append(
                                                '<input type="hidden" name="searchIndex" value="'+ui.item.idd+'" />');
                                $('#form1')
                                        .append(
                                                '<input type="hidden" name="searchCity" value="'+ui.item.label+'" />');
                            }
                        });
```

and in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getDataAU", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void populateAutocomplete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response,@RequestParam("term")String term){
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try{
        obj.put("label","Nepal");
        obj.put("category", "country");
        obj.put("idd", "2");
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();    }

    String send = gson.toJson(obj);
    System.out.println(send);
    try {
        response.getWriter().write(send);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```